# F# AST transformation

Tags: f#, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree, cil, quotations

Hi I'm looking for guidance on the best way forwards, I want to take valid F# code and run a transformation at the AST level to generate a new AST which is then compiled and loaded. As an example I might want to run a CPS transform on the AST. Interestingly the input to the transform would be valid type checked F# code, embedding valid f# code in quotations in this example would seem pretty ugly. Adding an attribute to every let definition would also be onerous. Ideally I'd take an existing module, get the AST of all the definitions inside and run my transform to generate a new module with the transformation added.

Comment: I voted to close the question as too broad. The question is asking for guidance and best way. Both words are red flags for subjective answers and SO is about objective answers. Could you please ask a subjective question with the code you have attempted and any problems you are having. :)

Comment: Fair point, where would be a good forum to ask the question?

Comment: Try [F# Discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fsharp-opensource) or check out other resources at the [F# Software Foundation](http://fsharp.org/)

Comment: There is also an active channel in the Slack. Perhaps it makes sense to ask there.

Comment: @Guy Coder, Thank you. I meant [it](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/)